# AndEngine gles2 Physics

Tags: java, android, andengine, android-virtual-device

I tried to copy and paste a physics example in the AndEngine example package.

No errors appeared but when I run it the emulator says "Unfortunately PhysicsActivity has stopped".

The emulator is on API 15, gpu is on, magnetic field support and accelerometer is also on.

Here are the codes:

```
package physics.jet;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.IOnAreaTouchListener;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.ITouchArea;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.shape.IAreaShape;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.constants.PhysicsConstants;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.AccelerationData;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.IAccelerationListener;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObjectManager;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.MouseJoint;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.MouseJointDef;

/**
 * @author albrandroid
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
 * @since 10:35:23 - 28.02.2011
 */
public class PhysicsActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener, IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;

    private TiledTextureRegion mBoxFaceTextureRegion;
    private TiledTextureRegion mCircleFaceTextureRegion;

    private Scene mScene;

    private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
    private int mFaceCount = 0;

    private MouseJoint mMouseJointActive;
    private Body mGroundBody;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add objects.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box_tiled.png", 0, 0, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_circle_tiled.png", 0, 32, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
        this.mScene.setOnAreaTouchListener(this);

        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
        this.mGroundBody = this.mPhysicsWorld.createBody(new BodyDef());

        final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
        this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
        this.mScene.attachChild(left);
        this.mScene.attachChild(right);

        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGameCreated() {
        this.mEngine.enableVibrator(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    this.addFace(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
                    return true;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(this.mMouseJointActive != null) {
                        final Vector2 vec = Vector2Pool.obtain(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
                        this.mMouseJointActive.setTarget(vec);
                        Vector2Pool.recycle(vec);
                    }
                    return true;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(this.mMouseJointActive != null) {
                        this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(this.mMouseJointActive);
                        this.mMouseJointActive = null;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final ITouchArea pTouchArea, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            final IAreaShape face = (IAreaShape) pTouchArea;
            /*
             * If we have a active MouseJoint, we are just moving it around
             * instead of creating a second one.
             */
            if(this.mMouseJointActive == null) {
                this.mEngine.vibrate(100);
                this.mMouseJointActive = this.createMouseJoint(face, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
        this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();

        this.disableAccelerationSensor();
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    public MouseJoint createMouseJoint(final IAreaShape pFace, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        final Body body = (Body) pFace.getUserData();
        final MouseJointDef mouseJointDef = new MouseJointDef();

        final Vector2 localPoint = Vector2Pool.obtain((pTouchAreaLocalX - pFace.getWidth() * 0.5f) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, (pTouchAreaLocalY - pFace.getHeight() * 0.5f) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
        this.mGroundBody.setTransform(localPoint, 0);

        mouseJointDef.bodyA = this.mGroundBody;
        mouseJointDef.bodyB = body;
        mouseJointDef.dampingRatio = 0.95f;
        mouseJointDef.frequencyHz = 30;
        mouseJointDef.maxForce = (200.0f * body.getMass());
        mouseJointDef.collideConnected = true;

        mouseJointDef.target.set(body.getWorldPoint(localPoint));
        Vector2Pool.recycle(localPoint);

        return (MouseJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(mouseJointDef);
    }

    private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
        this.mFaceCount++;
        Debug.d("Faces: " + this.mFaceCount);

        final AnimatedSprite face;
        final Body body;

        if(this.mFaceCount % 2 == 0) {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        } else {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        }
        face.setUserData(body);
        face.animate(200);

        this.mScene.registerTouchArea(face);
        this.mScene.attachChild(face);

        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it on a device cause AndEngineGles2 does not work whit the emulator

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I believe this is no longer true. I can run AndEngine examples on 4.0.3 with Google API 16, with GPU Emulation enabled. This cannot be done within a Virtual Machine.